# AngularJS directive : require ngBind

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm currently writing an attribute directive relying on the use of ngBind. I need the element to bear a ngBind attribute for the directive to work. I was thinking that a simple `require: 'ngBind'` would be enough, just like you'd do with `ngModel`. So here's what I did :

```
app.directive( 'myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require:  'ngBind',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) { .. }
});
```

And here's how I use my directive:

```
<span my_directive="" ng_bind="valueToBeBound"></span>
```

But then I get this error, so I suppose it can't be done this way:

```
Error: error:ctreq
Missing Required Controller
Controller 'ngBind', required by directive 'myDirective', can't be found!
```

Is there any means to force the presence of `ngBind` ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour. As defined in the AngularJS documentation for a directive's [**`require`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) option states that:

> Require another directive and inject its **controller** as the fourth
>   argument to the linking function. The require takes a string name (or
>   array of strings) of the directive(s) to pass in. If an array is used,
>   the injected argument will be an array in corresponding order. If no
>   such directive can be found, or **if the directive does not have a**
>   **controller, then an error is raised (unless no link function is**
>   **specified, in which case error checking is skipped)**.

Since the `ngBind` directive required by `myDirective` does not have a controller then an error is expected to be raised, unless you remove the link function in your `myDirective` directive then angular will simply skip the error checking.

There are two ways to achieve what you want.

1. Remove the `link()` function in your `myDirective` directive then add a controller function in that directive to add your component logic. The problem with this solution is that you can't attach DOM logic in your `link()` function.

---

2. The most ideal way to deal with the problem is to simply remove the `require` option and simply check the existence of the `ngBind` attribute in the element where your `myDirective` directive resides.

e.g.

```
app.directive( 'myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       if(angular.isUndefined(attrs.ngBind)) {
          return;
       }

       // Your myDirective DOM LOGIC/MANIPULATION should be here 

    }
});
```

Comment: I was going for the second solution indeed, but I would have liked to find a way to ensure that people that will need to use my directive won't forget to use a ``ngBind``, but well... Thanks for your detailed answer anyway.

Comment: In the second solution, you can throw an error or use `$log.warn()` before the return statement to notify the users of your directive that an `ngBind` must be present in the element.

Answer (score -1):

As explained well here: [Angular NgModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController) you need to provide the ngBind

```
<span ng-bind="ModelName"></span>
```

Comment: Actually not answering my question at all.

Comment: see ` ng_bind` , It's should be  `ng-bind`

Comment: and also you don't need to call the `my_directive`

Comment: Actually, Angular JS uses a more complex naming schema. When writing a directive, you use a ``camelCaseDirective`` name, but when using it in your HTML (since HTML is case-insensitive), you have to use a lower case form of the directive name, and there are several delimiters to separate words (``:``, ``-``, ``_``). You can have a look at the [AngularJS directive documentation page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives). Therefore, ``my-directive``, ``my_directive`` or ``my:directive`` are all valid.